# Property [expiry_date] does not exist on this collection instance. in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

[image][image]I have to disable the user all features if the user package expires in laravel. like I purchase a package for one month after one month package expires automatic and the user can't see any data that are coming from the database.

my expire date inserted automatically in the user table and I join my call log table. (Expire date automatic calculate from a package month **like : I select 1 month a package then it show exprie date auto in user table for 1 month**)

**my code is**

```
  public function index(){

   $calllog = DB::table('calllogs')->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'calllogs.user_id')->find();

    if($calllog->expiry_date > 'expiry_date'){
        return $this->sendResponse($calllog->toArray(), 'Package Expired Sorry!');
    }
    else{
        return $this->sendResponse($calllog->toArray(), 'Call Log retrieved successfully');   
    }
 }
```

please help

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if($calllog->expiry_date > 'expiry_date') should be     if($calllog->expiry_date > $today)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$calllog` is an array of object you should use `first()` instead of `get()` or use it like `$calllog[0]->expiry_date` what if I am understanding your requirements correctly then it should be `$calllog[0]->expiry_date` try this :

```
 public function index(){
   $calllog = DB::table("calllogs")->join("users", "users.id", "=", "calllogs.user_id")->get();

   if($calllog[0]->expiry_date > 'expiry_date'){
     return $this->sendResponse($calllog->toArray(), 'Package Expired Sorry!');
   }
   else{
    return $this->sendResponse($calllog->toArray(), 'Call Log retrieved successfully');   
  }
}
```

Comment: I make changes but now I get this message "Cannot use object of type stdClass as array" please tell me why is it. I just do if user login after the expiry date his/her all data hide. Please gide me

Comment: which one you've tried .. don't try both just replace `$calllog->expiry_date` with `$calllog[0]->expiry_date` in your code

Comment: when you do `get()` you get an array of objects but when you do `first()` you get an object as I can see you've to return multiple call_logs I suggest you do get and check with `$calllog[0]->expiry_date`

Comment: also you are returning all the data if it is expired are you sure it is correct logic ?@ayushflitzip

Comment: yes you should not use `first()` and then `$calllog[0]->expiry_date` ... please check my other comment to understand

Comment: I do this and it gives a response dd($calllog);

Comment: i've updated my answer with the correct code please check it and compare with your's you'll understand where you are going wrong

Comment: yes, now it gives a response and sorry for the late response. but still, my answer is not complete I need it if the expiry date is 2020-02-26 and I logged at 2020-02-27 then my dashboard features hide and give a message (Your Package is expire please upgrade it).

Comment: now it's working I use Carbon::now() in if-else condition, please see the answer and please update me if it is correct way or not????

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing a whole column since `$calllog` is a collection, not an element.
You should specify which of the rows in the table you want to compare. You can do this by using:

`$calllog = DB::table('calllogs')->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'calllogs.user_id')->find($id);`

for example. In case you want to compare them all, you'll have to loop through them.

Morover, **you are comparing it to a string** 'expiry_date' which is not a date...

Comment: thanks, @gamopo sir please explain to me more... now I get an undefined variable $id????...what is need for here find($id)

Comment: By using `->get()` you bring all the rows in the database. If you just want to compare one row you have to specify which one, you can do that using `->find($id)` where `$id` is a variable containing  the id of the row you want to compare or you can use `->first()` which will give you the first row. If you want to compare every row you have to use a `foreach($calllogs as $calllog)`

Answer (score 0):

The `get` method returns an instance of `Illuminate\Support\Collection` which is a **[wrapper for working with arrays of data](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-get)**

You are trying to access `expiry_date` on an array of objects

You may fix it by changing this line from

```
$calllog = DB::table('calllogs')->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'calllogs.user_id')->get();
```

to

```
$calllog = DB::table('calllogs')->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'calllogs.user_id')->first();
```

Comment: sir, I made changes according to you sittl it's not working...Now it gives a this message "Use of undefined constant expiry_date - assumed 'expiry_date' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)"